Do Elves interpret kissing or public displays of affection differently from humans?
In The Lord of the Rings: The Rings of Power S02E07 "Doomed to Die," there was a somewhat controversial scene: Elrond kissed Galadriel on the lips. This seemingly romantic or sexual kiss struck many viewers (including myself) as odd, considering that Galadriel later becomes Elrond's mother-in-law.
Robert Aramayo, who plays Elrond, clarified that the kiss wasn't romantic but rather a distraction for the Orcs. It was during this moment that Elrond secretly passed Galadriel a pin she'd later use as a lockpick to escape her chains. (The distraction worked so well that even I missed this detail until reading about it later!)
In an interview with Nerdist, Aramayo shared some interesting insights about Elven culture (emphasis mine):

Although I think that that act in this world is slightly different in the way it's perceived. I think when you see a kiss walking down the street, you instantly make certain conclusions about what's going on. But in the elven world, I think that's slightly different. And Miv (Morfydd Clark) spoke a lot about that, about how she looked at it differently and stuff.

When asked if elves kiss one another more freely than humans do, Aramayo responded (emphasis mine):

I think potentially. Yeah. That's the interesting thing about creating a fantasy world, isn't it? That you get to ask questions like that in these heightened worlds? You get to think, well, how do they communicate and what does that mean? I think, though, that what I'll run with is Elrond was trying to slip her the keys to get free.

This suggests that this kind of kissing (i.e., kissing someone on the lips for as long as Elrond kissed Galadriel) may not be as unusual or inherently romantic or sexual for Elves as it is for humans.
As Aramayo points out, this raises an interesting question: Was there a similar idea in Tolkien's original texts suggesting that Elves have a different view of public displays of affection compared to humans? In other words, could actions that humans typically consider romantic or sexual (like the Galadriel-Elrond kiss) be viewed differently in Elven culture? What information do we have about the culture of Elven kissing in Tolkien's legendarium?

Which human culture are you using as comparison? Various real human cultures look very differently at kissing or public displays of affection.

At some point you have to accept that Elves don't really exist, but also that any ideas that Tolkien might have had on the matter are irrelevant to the programme makers.

@KlausÆ.Mogensen You raise a fair point. But I'd argue that regardless of cultural differences, most humans would interpret that kiss as romantic, if not sexual (assuming they weren't aware of the context). That's why it sparked controversy. The question is more about how Elves might view such actions differently from humans in general.

Keyword "later" mother-in-law.  (To be fair I didn't realize that was the case when I saw all the youtubers being outraged at clueless writing.)

@lucasbachmann Imagine tying the knot with someone knowing you've smooched their mother in the past.

One does not simply kiss Galadriel...

I don't recall now anything in particular that reinforces this idea, but a significant part of our modern conception of elven culture derives from Tolkien works. Usually elven are somewhat repressed on modern fantasy works, used to show few emotions and often surprised and amused for how spontaneous and intense can human feelings be. I cannot state right now anything that points to this coming from Tolkien's depiction of elven culture, and not every modern work of fantasy shows those "Vulcanian" elven, but I'm pretty sure that there's some connection there.

@Bardo they have certainly adopted "Vulcanian" ears - more Star Trek than Tolkien!

I don't think we know much about kissing among Elves particularly, but we do have some idea of how they experienced sexual desire.
At the outset, it's worth noting that the makers of The Rings of Power are limited to the writings in the book of The Lord of the Rings itself, including the Appendices. They are explicitly not allowed to use anything Tolkien wrote outside of that, including what was later published as the Silmarillion, Unfinished Tales, History of Middle-Earth, etc.
Which is a shame, as in HoME we can see that Tolkien did go into great detail about the life-cycle of Elves; in particular we learn that their sexual desire ceases after they have had children. From HoME volume 10, Morgoth's Ring:

Doubtless they would retain for many ages the power of generation, if the will and desire were not satisfied; but with the exercise of the power the desire soon ceases, and the mind turns to other things.

That said, at this point Elrond has not had children, so he presumably still had sexual desire; we don't know when Celebrían, the daughter of Galadriel, was born, although one theory places it early in the Second Age, so maybe before the events of RoP.

Not sure why this is getting upvotes, it does not answer the actual question: Was there a similar idea in Tolkien's original texts suggesting that Elves have a different view of public displays of affection compared to humans? In other words, could actions that humans typically consider romantic or sexual (like the Galadriel-Elrond kiss) be viewed differently in Elven culture? What information do we have about the culture of Elven kissing in Tolkien's legendarium?
